# Kolab/Imapd authentication error

Tags: imap, kolab

I'm trying to install Kolab 16 on CentOS 7 but i have troubles to authenticate the user via IMAP. The maillog says:

```
May 30 14:35:11 mxname IMAPD-CUST/imaps[17908]: inittls: Loading hard-coded DH parameters
May 30 14:35:11 mxname IMAPD-CUST/imaps[17908]: starttls: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384 (256/256 bits reused) no authentication
```

Authentication with roundcubemail works like a charm. The relevant section from imapd.conf is (file permissions should be okay):

```
tls_server_cert: /etc/ssl/certs/fqdn.crt
tls_server_key: /etc/ssl/certs/fqdn.key
tls_server_ca_file: /etc/ssl/certs/fqdn.pem
tls_ciphers: EDH+CAMELLIA:EDH+aRSA:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+SHA384:EECDH+aRSA+SHA256:EECDH:+CAMELLIA256:+AES256:+CAMELLIA128:+AES128:+SSLv3:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!P
SK:!DSS:!RC4:!SEED:!ECDSA:CAMELLIA256-SHA:AES256-SHA:CAMELLIA128-SHA:AES128-SHA
```

I have no idea how to further investigate this issue. I found out that there is now an IMAP proxy (guam) in front of imapd (haven't seen that on my old setup), maybe this is the trouble maker? The maillog is not very useful for me atm. Any suggestions which service could make troubles here?

Comment: Are you actually using SSL/TLS cert-based authentication?  If not, this is all a red herring.

Comment: you mean client side certificates?

Comment: Yes, are you using client side certificates for authentication?

Comment: nope, username/password based auth

Comment: Then TLS has nothing to do with it.  Do you get an error?  a stacktrace?  etc.  If this is a general software problem, you should take it to superuser, as stackoverflow is for programming questions.